# Launch failure after Download of 2.80 & 2.79 on windows 10

Tags: blend-files

Currently have 2.79 on windows 10. Previously also had 2.80 but got rid of it to download a later build. Now WHEN I download it I cannot launch it successfully:

I proceed as normal to open it... ie click on blender.exe to launch it.But at this point it fails saying. " Code execution cannot proceed because the following cannot be found (though I can see them all there)..
avcodec-58.dll, python 37, SDL2, avformat-58.

Though I already have 2.79 working well - I  downloaded it again (to see if the problem was just 2.80 and when I came to launch it got...  code execution cannot proceed because following not found:
python 37.dll, libsndfile-1, open Al32, SDL2.dll

Any suggestions on how I can proceed to rectify this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please try to reform the question in a clear and consistent manner only using terminology that you are sure about.  If you cannot download it and it is not downloaded, what are you trying to run when you get the error message? What is a clean boot?.. If you want to run 2.80, you need to download it. It comes in a .zip file that you need to extract somewhere and only then you can run Blender from the folder that you extract from the downloaded zip archive file.

Comment: Thanks Martin Z & cegaton for directing me to better clarity

Comment: try uninstalling the program using the preferences in the operating system (or manually delete the contents of c:\Program Files\Blender Foundation,  then manually delete all contents from c:\\users\*your_user_name*\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender and re-install blender.

Comment: I followed your advice, cegaton and deleted anything related to 2.80 in the c:\\users etc....but am afraid to take 2.79 out in case I cannot get it in and working again. There was a bunch of straggling 2.80 data that I manually deleted but new efforts at launching  yielded the same result as before. Thanks for the suggestions. Guess I will uninstall all Blender soon but need 2.79 that is working right now. Thanks cegaton for your time and suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I think what's going on here is that double clicking the `zip` file in the file browser doesn't actually extract the `zip` file contents, it just gives you a view of the `zip` file contents. That looks just like if you had extracted the `zip` file.

What you should do is:

- Download the `zip` file
- Right click it and do "Extract all"
- After extraction is done, you should now be able to execute `blender.exe` from within the extracted folder.

One thing to look out for is that inside the not-extracted `zip` file, `blender.exe` will have a generic (non-Blender) icon.

After "Extract all", `blender.exe` will have the Blender icon.

The above instructions solved my problems when trying to run Blender 2.80 RC2 from a zip file on Windows.